# Wrong center point if view is inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am simply trying to get `UIButton`'s center point if I tap it to draw something on it. But the problem is that the center point is wrong. My buttons are inside of a `UIStackView`.

What I am trying to do inside button action:

```
let myButtonCenter = contentView.convert(sender.center, from: stackView)
```

but it gives me wrong `CGPoint()`.

This is my view stack:

[image]

I also tried like this:

```
func getTappedButtonCenter(sender: UIButton) -> CGPoint{
        var buttonsArray = [UIButton]()
        for view in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
            let horizontalStackView = view as! UIStackView
            for view in horizontalStackView.arrangedSubviews {
                let button = view as! UIButton

                buttonsArray.append(button)

            }
        }

        let buttonIndex = buttonsArray.index(of: sender)

        let tappedButton = buttonsArray[buttonIndex!] as! UIButton

        return convert(tappedButton.center, from: tappedButton)

    }
```

So my question is, how should I get view's center if it is inside `UIStackView`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the UIButton frame to the superview. Checkout [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622424-convert)

Answer (score 0):

What does "it gives me wrong CGPoint()" mean? A view's center is expressed in its superview's coordinate system. In this case, your buttons' superviews will be the stack view. If you want the center in the coordinate system fo your view controller's content view, you'll need to use one of the `UIView` conversion methods, like:

```
let temp = sender.center
let myButtonCenter = self.view.convert(temp, from: sender)
```

(Note that "self" is not needed in the code above, and is added to make it clear that `view` is the view controller's content view.)

Comment: The output is the exact same. What I want is the button center point. I have 4 rows and columns of buttons. All in UIStackView. I want to draw something in the center of a pressed button. But your version makes the output same.

Comment: We can't tell what your drawing code is doing. If you want help getting a specific result you've going to have to provide more information. My answer was based on a guess from your vague statement that "it gives me wrong CGPoint()"